# How can I insert a new line in sqlite in PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite, insert, newline

I'm using PHP in order to insert data in an sqlite database.

I have a string like the following:

```
$string =  "Good morning!<br />It is a wonderful day!<br />"
```

I would like to replace all occurrences of `<br />` with `\n`.

I did the following in PHP in order to replace the `<br />` but it did not work:

```
<?php
    $string =  "Good morning!<br />It is a wonderful day!<br />"
    $symbols =array('<br />');
    $replace_symbols = array('\\n');
    $string = str_replace($symbols, $replace_symbols,$string);
    //InsertIntoSqlite($db,$string);
?>
```

When I connect to the sqlite database with SQLITE manager, I see the following inserted in the database:

> `sqlite: Good morning!\nIt is a wonderful day!\n`

What can I do in order to fix that?

**SOLVED:**

I did the following:

```
<?php

    $string = str_replace("<br />","\n",$string);

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'`-quoted strings do not honor **ANY** escapes, except the escape itself. `'\t'` is not at tab character, it's a `\` followed by a `t`. You want `"\n"` instead, which is an actual newline.

```
echo '\\ \t \n \r'; // spits out: \ \t \n \r
echo "\\ \t \n \r"; // spits out \ [tab] [newline] [carriagereturn]
```

Comment: So, do I need to use double quotes instead of single quotes?

Comment: Yes, and only one backslash. If you just blindly change your code to `"\\n"`, you'll STILL get `\n` in your output, because ``\\`` will be parsed first and reduced to just ``\``, leaving you with a ``\`` and an `n` char in your string, not a newline char.

Comment: Thanks for that, It worked for me! I can see the new line in sqlite now!

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem with &quot; when I do: `$string = str_replace("&quot;","'",$string);` OR `$string = str_replace("&quot;","\'",$string);` I get the following error in PHP:Warning: SQLite3::exec(): near &quot;the&quot; can not insert, What can I do in order to fix that? Thanks